# Is there any library that works like vuex or redux in any javascript application?

Tags: javascript, database, redux, vuex

I do not have enough knowledge to give a technical explanation, so I'll illustrate the problem.

I have a simple program, on node, starting from the "main.js" file. What I want is to manipulate the data in memory, globally, in an organized way. My program is too simple to use a database, but creating functions just to do a CRUD in JSON isn't very interesting. So I thought about Vuex.

This code below is example from the documentation.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: [
      { id: 1, text: '...', done: true },
      { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    doneTodos: state => {
      return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done)
    }
  }
})
```

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 1
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      // mutate state
      state.count++
    }
  }
})
```

I want to be able to, at least, create state, getters and commit mutations.

Comment: are you using your application as a backend? any framework you are using?

Comment: it's a whatsapp bot. I'm using only whatsapp-web.js (puppeteer), axios and cheerio. the reason why I need a globa state is to share information between components (each whatsapp command is build as a separated module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy to write some code to approximate what the vue store class is doing. It seems to take a constructor with some initial `state`, and optional `getters` and/or `mutation` methods which act on that state.

This is a rather rudamentry implementation, which hides away the state to stop it being changed externally.

```
class MyStore
{
  constructor(info) {
    const state = info.state;
        
    info.getters && Object.entries(info.getters).forEach( ([method, impl]) => {
      this[method] = () => impl(state)
    });
    
    info.mutations && Object.entries(info.mutations).forEach( ([method, impl]) => {
      this[method] = () => impl(state);
    });
    
  }
}
```

You can see this working with both your examples below (note I made `state` inaccessible directly so had to add a `getter` to the second example to read the current `count` state):

```js
class MyStore
{
  constructor(info) {
    const state = info.state;
        
    info.getters && Object.entries(info.getters).forEach( ([method, impl]) => {
      this[method] = () => impl(state)
    });
    
    info.mutations && Object.entries(info.mutations).forEach( ([method, impl]) => {
      this[method] = () => impl(state);
    });
    
  }
}


const store1 = new MyStore({
  state: {
    todos: [
      { id: 1, text: '...', done: true },
      { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    doneTodos: state => {
      return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done)
    }
  }
})


console.log(store1.doneTodos())

const store2 = new MyStore({
  state: {
    count: 1
  },
  getters: {
    currentCount: state => state.count
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      // mutate state
      state.count++
    }
  }
})

store2.increment();
console.log(store2.currentCount());
```

Comment: man, you are awesome. did something so complex for me in such beautiful code. I will definitely try this, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Redux is framework agnostic, so you can just use Redux (or better, Redux Toolkit) with plain JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. until now I've only used vue and vuex, I just know what redux do because it's mentioned in the vuex docs. I actually made a very stupid question so. Gonna check redux later, thanks for say that

Comment: Best place to get started is the official tutorial - good luck! :)
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts